# Writing structured binary files in haskell

Tags: haskell, binaryfiles

I want to write a structured binary file in Haskell.
For example, assume that the first four bytes should be "TEST" (as ASCII), followed by the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, then 32 bytes each with the value 128 and then the number 2048 in Little Endian format.

That means, the created file (as hex) should look like this:

> 54 45 53 54 01 02 03 04 80 80 [... 30 bytes more ...] 00 08

So basically I have a custom data structure, let's say

```
data MyData = MyData {
  header :: String     -- "TEST"
  n1     :: Integer    -- 1
  n2     :: Integer    -- 2
  n3     :: Integer    -- 3
  block  :: [Integer]  -- 32 times 128
  offset :: Integer    -- 2048
}
```

Now I want to write this data to file. So basically I need to convert this structure into one long ByteString. I could not find out a clean idiomatic way to do this. Ideally I have a function

```
MyDataToByteString :: MyData -> ByteString
```

or

```
MyDataToPut :: MyData -> Put
```

but I could not find out how to create such a function.

Background information: I want to write a song in the impulse tracker format (http://schismtracker.org/wiki/ITTECH.TXT), which is the binary format for the schism tracker software.

**Update 1**

For the endian conversion, I guess I can just extract the individual Bytes as follows:

```
getByte :: Int -> Int -> Int
getByte b num = shift (num .&. bitMask b) (8-8*b)
  where bitMask b = sum $ map (2^) [8*b-8 .. 8*b-1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this one (not optimal, I am afraid):

```
import qualified Data.List as L
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BC
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

data MyData = MyData {
      header :: String     -- "TEST"
    , n1     :: Integer    -- 1
    , n2     :: Integer    -- 2
    , n3     :: Integer    -- 3
    , n4     :: Integer    -- 4
    , block  :: [Integer]  -- 32 times 128
    , offset :: [Integer]  -- 2048 in little endian
} deriving (Show)

d = MyData "TEST" 1 2 3 4 (L.replicate 32 128) [0, 8]

myDataToByteString :: MyData -> B.ByteString
myDataToByteString (MyData h n1 n2 n3 n4 b o) =
    B.concat [
          BC.pack h
        , B.pack (map fromIntegral [n1, n2, n3, n4])
        , B.pack (map fromIntegral b)
        , B.pack (map fromIntegral o)
    ]
```

Comment: That's great, but you cheated a little bit - you manually entered `[0, 8]` as the little endian representation for 2048. So how do I arrive there programmatically?

Comment: @Julian Oh, you can use functions of `Data.Bits` to do that, it should not be hard.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I guess that will do the trick (see update in question).

Answer (score 3):

The `binary` or `cereal` package provide easy `ByteString` serialization of data structures. Here's an example using `binary`

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-} 

import Data.Binary
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8
import Data.Word8                  
import GHC.Generics

data MyData = MyData                  
    { header :: B8.ByteString               
    , n1     :: Int                 
    , n2     :: Int                  
    , n3     :: Int                 
    , n4     :: Int                 
    , block  :: [Word8]               
    , offset :: Int                 
    } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance Binary MyData

myData = MyData (B8.pack "Test") 1 2 3 4 (replicate 32 128) 2048
```

Notice I've changed the type of `block` to `[Word8]` as the question states that these are to be *bytes*.

We derive a `GHC.Generics` instance for `MyData` which allows the `binary` package to automatically generate a `Binary` instance. Now we can serialize our data to `ByteString` using `encode`, and deserialize with `decode`:

```
λ. let encoded = encode myData
λ. :t encoded
encoded :: Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
λ. let decoded = decode encoded :: MyData
λ. decoded
MyData {header = "Test", n1 = 1, n2 = 2, n3 = 3, n4 = 4, block = [128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128,128], offset = 2048}
```

Comment: I cannot get your example to run. If I load your main file in ghci, I get `Not in scope: type constructor or class 'ByteString'`. If I add `import qualified Data.ByteString as B` and change `ByteString` to `B.ByteString`, I get `Couldn't match expected type 'B.ByteString' with actual type '[Char]'`

Comment: @Julian: I've edited my answer to include imports and proper `String` to `ByteString` conversion.

Comment: That helped a lot - but when I try to display or save the encoded ByteString, I still get a `No instance nor default method for class operation Data.Binary.put`. What am I missing?

Comment: If you're running this code in `ghci` make sure you're using `:set -XDeriveGeneric`

Comment: Doesn't change anything, same thing when I run with "runhaskell". The error occurs when I try to do `BS.writeFile "test" encoded` or `BS.putStr encoded`. I guess I am using the wrong ByteString module (I use `import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS`).